# connect Navicat for mysql to xampp server

Tags: mysql, navicat

I'm trying to connect Navicat with my xampp mysql server on mac but I'm getting this error constantly

> Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

Comment: How did you install it? Did you configure it as service?

Comment: @MaartenDev sorry what do you mean I install it directly from their site didn't change or configure anything